# Using genetic algorithm to minimize the MSE with the FIR filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, geneticsharp

This code for generate the training sequence, how can I use this sequence to 
train the FIR and GA with the optimal parameters?

```
% Simulate some (useful) signal to be transmitted
a= (randn(500,1)>0) *2-1; % Random bipolar (-1,1) sequence;

% CHANNEL MODEL
W=3.5; %corresponds to high channel distortion
h= [ 0, 0.5 * (1+cos(2*pi/W*(-1:1))) ]; % create a 5 tap channel impulse response.

ah=conv(h,a);

v= sqrt(0.001)*randn(500,1); % Gaussian noise with variance 0.001;
u=ah(1:500)+v;

subplot(221) , stem(impz(h,1,10)), title('Channel input response h(n)')
subplot(222) , stem(ah(1:59)), title('Convolved (distorted) signal h*a')
subplot(223) , stem(a(1:59)), title('Original signal to be transmitted')
subplot(224) , stem(u(1:59)), title('Received signal (noise + distortion)')
```

Comment: um, well, you don't do any neural optimization in your code, let alone calculate the error, so what about starting with that?

Comment: thank you for replying... actually I change my strategy I started with Gaussian pulse first to train the genetic algorithm I use this scenario :          Xrange=-2.2:0.1:3.25;
mu=1;
sigma=0.25;
g_pulse= 1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) * exp( - ( Xrange - mu).^2/(2*sigma^2));
figure(1)
%plot(Xrange,g_pulse,'r', 'linewidth',2);
hold on
g_pulse_max=g_pulse/max(g_pulse);
plot(g_pulse_max);
hold on 
x_max=x/max(x);
plot(x_max);
hold on
length(Xrange)  the problem is I  dont know how to enter it to the GA tool to get the output and after that calculate MSE for the output signal